# Examples of modules that $M_\mathfrak{p} \subset N_\mathfrak{p}$ that does not imply $M \subset N$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory, localization, dedekind-domain

I came across a theorem in algebraic number theory:

> **Theorem** Let $A$ be a Dedekind ring and $M, N$ two modules over $A$. If $M_\mathfrak{p} \subset N_\mathfrak{p}$ for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$, then $M \subset N$.

*Proof.* Let $a \in M$. For each $\mathfrak{p}$ we can find $x_\mathfrak{p} \in N$ and $s_\mathfrak{p} \in A \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ such that $a/1=x_\mathfrak{p}/s_\mathfrak{p}$. Let $\mathfrak{b}$ be the prime ideal generated by *the* $s_\mathfrak{p}$. Then $\mathfrak{b}$ is the unit ideal, and we can write
\[
1=\sum y_\mathfrak{p}s_\mathfrak{p}
\]
with elements $y_\mathfrak{p} \in A$ all but a finite number of which are $0$. This yields
\[
a = \sum y_\mathfrak{p}s_\mathfrak{p}a = \sum y_\mathfrak{p}x_\mathfrak{p} \in N
\]
as desired. $\square$

---

Here $M_\mathfrak{p}$ means the localisation of $M$ at $\mathfrak{p}$.

My question is not about the theorem per se, but I guess there should be some counterexamples. Chances are there are modules $M,N$ such that

$$
M_\mathfrak{p} \subset N_\mathfrak{p} \text{ does not imply } M \subset N.
$$

But I find it pretty hard to construct an example. I try to breakdown this question into pieces:

1. Does this coincide with local property? It's pretty close:

> Let $\phi:M \to N$ be an $A$-modue homomorphism (no futher property assumed on $A$ at this point), then the followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\phi$ is injective.
> 2. $\phi_\mathfrak{p}:M_\mathfrak{p} \to N_\mathfrak{p}$ is injective for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.
> 3. $\phi_\mathfrak{m}:M_\mathfrak{m} \to N_\mathfrak{m}$ is injective for each maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

It looks like we are talking about 2 implies 1. But the inclusion map $M \to N$ is not given in this theorem. Also in the proof of the theorem, Serge Lang used properties of Dedekind ring (fractional ideals form a group) explicitly. If local property is the case, why would he ignore it?

2. Is it possible to get a desired counterexample given by $M_\mathfrak{p} \not\subset N_\mathfrak{p}$ for at least one prime ideal?
3. Is it possible to get a desired counterexample given by $A$ not being Dedekind, or even wilder, $A$ is not Noetherian? Noetherian counterexamples will certainly be more interesting.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit 1: I added proof of the theorem to avoid unnecessary confusion.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about $X\subset Y$ without some way to compare $X$ and $Y$ - they should both be submodules of some other module, for instance. But you don't mention anything of the sort: what do you mean when you say $\subset$? How are you comparing things?

Comment: @KReiser This is a good question and I didn't make it clear myself. I will add proof from the original book.

Comment: Your edit does not address the issue: you still have to explain how you are comparing $M$ and $N$ (resp. $M_p$ and $N_p$).

Comment: According to the proof I think Lang used $\subset$ to simply denote submodule. Firstly he wrote $a/1 = x_\mathfrak{p}/s_\mathfrak{p} \in N_\mathfrak{p}$, and he proved $a \in N$ in the end. Do you think it solves the issue?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the claim is true for any unital ring $R$. Indeed, suppose that $M_\mathfrak p \subseteq N_\mathfrak p$ for all prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ of $R$.

Let $a \in M$. Then for any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ we consider $\frac a1 \in M_\mathfrak p \subseteq N_\mathfrak p$. Hence there exist $n_\mathfrak p \in N$ and $s_\mathfrak p,t_\mathfrak p \in R-\mathfrak p$, s.t.

$$t_\mathfrak p(s_\mathfrak pa-n_\mathfrak p) = 0$$

Now consider the ideal $I$ of $R$ generated by all the elements $t_\mathfrak ps_\mathfrak p$. We claim that it is the whole ring $R$. Suppose the opposite is true, then you can find a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ containing it. However, then we get $t_\mathfrak ms_\mathfrak m \in I \subseteq \mathfrak m$, which is a contradiction, as $t_\mathfrak ms_\mathfrak m \in R- \mathfrak m$. Hence $I=R$. In particular, we can find $y_\mathfrak p \in R$, s.t.

$$1 = \sum_\mathfrak p y_\mathfrak pt_\mathfrak ps_\mathfrak p$$

where all but finitely many of the $y_\mathfrak p$ are $0$. Therefore:

$$a = \sum_\mathfrak p y_\mathfrak pt_\mathfrak ps_\mathfrak pa = \sum_\mathfrak p (y_\mathfrak pt_\mathfrak p)n_\mathfrak p \in N$$

Hence $M \subseteq N$.

---

From the proof we can notice that we can relax the condition and ask for $M_\mathfrak m \subseteq N_\mathfrak p$ for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak m$ of $R$, which is a common feature when it comes to localizing at prime ideals.

Comment: Basically you have just recovered Lang's proof without the assumption of being Dedekind. So following your proof, may I say that the potential counterexample can only be found in this way? If $M_\mathfrak{p} \subset N_\mathfrak{p}$ holds for *not all* prime ideals, then we may have $M \not\subset N$. Or consider maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "My question is not about the theorem per se, but I guess there should be some counterexamples. Chances are there are modules $M,N$ such that $M_p⊂N_p$ does not imply $M⊂N$."

**Answer:** Let $A$ be any commutative unital ring and let $L,L'$ be invertible $A$-modules with

$$L_{\mathfrak{p}}\cong L_{\mathfrak{p}}' \cong A_{\mathfrak{p}}$$

for all primes. Hence there is an abstract inclusion $L_{\mathfrak{p}}\subseteq L'_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for any prime ideal.This does not imply there is a "global" inclusion $L \subseteq L'$.

**Example:** Let $K$ be any number field with ring of integers $A$, and let $I,J$ be two invertible $A$-modules that are not contained in each other. This gives a counter example: The $A$-modules $I,J$ have isomorphic stalks since they both have rank one.

Comment: The example you gave is definitely not working, since $A$ is a Dedekind domain and we know the theorem to be true in that case. In fact, it is not hard to see this using the unique factorization of ideals into primes and using that if $\mathfrak p^a \mid I$ is the highest power of $\mathfrak p$ dividing $I$, then $I_\mathfrak p = \mathfrak p^aA_\mathfrak p$.

In fact, there isn't such a counterexample in the realm of unital rings, as shown in my proof.